# How can i make a random choice based on 2 values?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a random choice based on the value of a range of integers and a string.
I want my program to pick a random value from my string array, when the integer and the string matches.

I'm trying to explain it here:

```
public String Switch(int paramInt, String paramString, String joke, Context paramContext) {


    if ((paramInt >= -50) && (paramInt < -15)) {
        if ((paramString.contains("clear")) && (paramString.contains("day")))
        {
            paramString = paramContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.minus15to0ClearDay);
            joke.setText(paramString[new java.util.Random().nextInt(paramString.length)]);
        }
        return joke;
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this compile? `joke` can't be returned. It's not a String. `paramString` is not an array

Comment: No, it does not.

Comment: Are you new to Android, or Java? Because these are purely Java problems.

Comment: Yes-yes. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic structure is fine, but your types don't match.

Looks like you're dealing with weather, so I renamed everything to make sense

```
public String getWeatherCondition(int temp, String weather, Context c) {

    Random r = new java.util.Random();

    if (temp >= -50 && temp < -15) {
        if (weather.contains("clear") && weather.contains("day")) {
            String[] conditions = c.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.minus15to0ClearDay);
            return conditions[r.nextInt(conditions.length)]);
        }
    }
    return "none";
}
```

Use `joke.setText(getWeatherCondition(...))` elsewhere

Comment: Yes, I'm dealing with weather. Thank you, for the help. It works, learned today something. (switched rand with r)